# iSeries Command that displays PF DDS

Tags: ibm-midrange

Hi I came across some documentation where I could see the DDS of a PF in the below format.

```
File  . . . . :  XXXXXX      Text . . . .  XXXXXXX        
  Library . . :  XXXXXX      Member . . :  XXXXX                             
Position to Record Format . . . . . . . .  XXXXX     Name, F4 for list      
Position to Field Name  . . . . . . . . .              Name/*FIRST/*LAST/Gen.*
Position to Text Containing . . . . . . .                                     
Single Record Text/Field Name . . . . . .  TXT   XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX             
Mult Record Text/Field/Column Heading . .  TXT   XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX              
Select/Remove field Auto Dup  . . . . . .  RMV   SEL/RMV                      

           Display New  New  Auto Upper Allow   Field                         
Seq# Select Only   Line Page Dup  Case  Null    Name     Type Length Dec   Loc
   10           Company Number            K01   WDCOMP     S      2   0      1
   20           Order Number                    XXXXX#     P      7   0      3
   30           Invoice Number            K02   XXXXX#     S      6   0      7
   40           Invoice Sequence          K03   XXXXX     S      7   0     13
   50           Line Number               K04   XXXXX     P      3   0     20
```

Please note I have hidden some information by using character X.

Now my question is, what tool or command on the iSeries displays DDS information like the above? It might be the case that there is something in Aldon that does this.

Answer (score 1):

got the answer. Its DBU once you start DBU using the DBU or STRDBU command, give the program name and lib name and press F4 (Display Fields) this comes up. How cool is that :)

Comment: Note that DBU is a popular 3rd party utility.  The OS provides the Display File Description (DSPFD) command and the Display File Field Description (DSPFFD) command.

Comment: That's right. But I dont think those commands would display the field details in this format.

Comment: @user3311539 Is there a reason that the `format` makes any difference at all? DSPFFD can output to a database file so you can then print/display in any format you might imagine.

Comment: If you read my question, you can understand that this is the format that has been used to document file structures in my shop. I could write an RPG program that produces this format. But when we have DBU already, why create a new program?

Comment: Makes sense. Your question made it seem like you were looking for displayed or printed output in a particular output format. A QM query and form could be all that's need for output format, so was curious why the format was of interest. A DBU evaluation could have been used in the past, and now it's clear that you maintain a license.

Answer (score 0):

Command-> IMPDDS FILE(name_file) FILELIB(lib_file)